# pivot syntactically correct but logically incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My code is creating pivot syntactically correct but logically it is incorrect. 
Here is my excel sheet. What it is showing that highlighted in yellow in a sales order which has item # 10 ordered in quantity of 2500. Since it was shipped in broken shipments(highlighted in green), it has 4 line items(highlighted in yellow).
[image]

My code to create pivot.

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df2,
                           index=['Customer_Name'],
                           values=[
                               'Billed_Net_Value',
                               'Sales_Order_Net_Value',
                               'Open_Amount'],
                           aggfunc=np.sum,
                           margins=True)
```

### End result:

[image]

See that end result highlight in yellow has $2500 * 4 and $9500 * 4. It should really be counted once. Any tips on how to do that?

### Expected numbers

It should be 75475 - (2500 * 3) - (9500 * 3) = 39475. If instead of counting 2500 * 3 times and 9500 * 3 times we only count them once, the numbers will be correct.

Comment: I believe the issue here is that you are specifying `aggfunc=np.sum` for every pivot column. What is the expected/desired value for Sales_Order_Net_Value for Customer A?

Comment: @mmenschig is correct. You will need to provide a custom function for each aggregating column to tell pandas to do a very specific aggregation for that column. I'm not sure you can do this with `pivot_table` but you can certainly do this with `groupby`

Comment: Can we add groupby(sales order, so item) in pivot?

Comment: @nomad Yes you can group by as many columns as you would like using the `index` parameter

Comment: @TedPetrou Oh yes! But what it does to my layout is that it adds sales order and so item in the pivot. In simple language, I am trying to group them just for calculating the numbers but when displaying them, I just want them to show as shown above.

Comment: Whats the rule for counting once. Same Sales Order, SO Item and Material or just Sales Order and SO Item?